# appending a div jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to append a new `#questionfield` to the existing div `#questionfield` when the user clicks the button with id `#add`.

```
<div id="questionfield">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textinput">
              <input name="" id="textinput3" placeholder="Enter question here..." value=""
              type="text">
          </div>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
                  <legend>
                      Response Type:
                  </legend>
                  <input id="radio1" name="" value="radio1" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                  <label for="radio1">
                      Checkbox
                  </label>
                  <input id="radio2" name="" value="radio2" type="radio">
                  <label for="radio2">
                      Text Input
                  </label>
                  <input id="radio3" name="" value="radio3" type="radio">
                  <label for="radio3">
                      Number Input
                  </label>
              </fieldset>
          </div>
      </div>
      <a data-role="button" id="add">
          Add New Question
          <script>
                $("#add").click(function(){
                    $("#questionfield").append("<div id="questionfield"></div>");
                });
          </script>
      </a>
```

Comment: __IDs must be unique.__ Apart from that use quotes properly

Comment: sometimes it will allow you to do this, but then you'll get strange results when you try to work with them.

Comment: The line `$("#questionfield").append("<div id="questionfield"></div>");` is quoted improperly. Should be `$("#questionfield").append("<div id=\"questionfield\"></div>");`

Comment: Fix the quotes and move the script after the closing tag of the link.  It doesn't exist on the DOM until you close it.

Comment: sorry, would you mind clarifying? not sure I understand. where am I moving the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change syntax of append.

```
  $("#questionfield").append('<div id="questionfield1"></div>');
```

**Edit**

```
<a data-role="button" id="add">Add New Question</a>
<script>
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#questionfield").append("<div id='questionfield1'></div>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! it isn't appending `#questionfield` at the moment, unfortunately. It is appending it to the right place, but just not appending anything

Comment: That's only a part of the problem.  It won't work if you just fix that.

Comment: i see. What else is preventing me from appending?

Comment: Don't use same id of div while appending div.it should be *unique*.

Comment: If i were to change the original div to `<div class="questionfield" id="question1">` and then to change the append to `$("#question1").append('<div class="questionfield"></div>');`, it still doesn't work

Comment: did you close `<a data-role="button" id="add"> Add New Question</a>` tag before using it as mention by @Archer?

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand. What do you mean by closing the `#add` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` must be unique, you can use class instead. Besides that you also need to apply quotes and double quotes properly here:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#questionfield").append('<div class="questionfield"></div>');
    // --------                ^ use quotes here instead of "    ^
});
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're putting `<script></script>` tag inside `<a></a>`. You should placed scripts at the end of your page before closing `</body>` tag especially when you're not wrapping youur jQuery code inside DOM ready handler `$(function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,You have used incorrect combination of quotes while appending.(You will find the error in console for same)

Second, using duplicate IDs is bad practise.

Third, make sure that you write the code in DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#add").click(function(){
      $("#questionfield").append("<div id='questionfield'></div>");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you're closing the quotes when you're trying to set the id of the element. To fix this, you could either escape the quotes in the element like:

`$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#questionfield").append("<div id=\"questionfield\"></div>");
 });`

or use single quotes for the string (or the id value):

`$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#questionfield").append('<div id="questionfield"></div>');
 });`

Also, your element's ids should be unique, so you should change id to class `<div class="questionfield"></div>` or set a unique id for each element (which would be more troublesome to do, in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Change this part...

```
<a data-role="button" id="add">
    Add New Question
    <script>
        $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#questionfield").append("<div id="questionfield"></div>");
        });
    </script>
</a>
```

to this...

```
<a data-role="button" id="add">Add New Question</a>
<script>
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#questionfield").append("<div id='questionfield'></div>");
    });
</script>
```

You had `</a>` *after* the script, which means the link didn't exist at the time that the script was trying to reference it.